# All layer in QField-project are greyed out and not visible

Tags: qgis, qfield, digitizing, orthophoto, qfieldsync

I wanted to create a QField project with orthophotos from different years to digitise a how a river basin changed due to erosion. However, when I load the project in QField onto my iPad it only shows the OSM base layer. The orthophotos are merged and converted into Geopackage format but won't appear as well as one shape layer which roughly follows the river path (line layer).

[image: My greyed out layers]

Before I tried to import the photos as .tif but didn't work either and took a lot of storage space.

In the log messages it showed a warning concerning the projection but I don't really get it since it worked fine in QGIS Desktop. (There is one layer though having a different projection than the others).

[image: Log Messages]

How do I get my orthophotos to show up in QField?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to be sure, but certainly download and install the Transformation grid file referred to in your log messages. See manual [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#datum-transformations).

Note, in Windows, the correct folder for my system is not

> C:\OSGeo464W\

it is

> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.16\share\proj

You also need to install on your mobile device. I don't know the correct location on iOS, but for my two Android devices it is at

> ..\Internal storage\Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\QField\proj

Note, in Android you can only access this location using a cable connection, and not by browsing from the device itself.

Hope this helps